# How to sign my Expo app with my current Google Play keystore?

Tags: android, expo, google-play, keystore, android-app-signing

I need to sign my app in Expo with the current keystore of my outdated app in google play. The problem I got is I cannot download the *.keystore or *.jks from my console.

If I use another keystore, the current users of the app won't see my new version as an upgrade, but as a new app (as far as I know). So Expo is asking me to upload this keystore file to sign my app with the same key used in the previous version, but I can't find where to donwload it.

The previous version of the app was created using Adalo (a no-code app builder) and they won't let me download the keystore used the first time.

If someone has passed through this, I will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

I tried generating my app from Expo CLI, but it was signed with a different key before generating my *.aab file. But when I tried to upload it to a new version of my app in Google Play, it says the key is different and I was unable to upload it.

Comment: Any inputs on this, stuck with same issue